# Mapping over values from Strapi when used with React-Query

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, strapi, react-query

I have used React-Query many times, but when I return an API call from Strapi, I receive the error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

It's basically a simple function call as follows:

```
export default function ProductList() {
  const { data: products, isLoading } = useQuery('Products', () => 
    axios('/api/products').then((res) => res.data.products)
  );

  if (isLoading) return <LoadingSpinner />

  return products.map((product) => (
    <ProductItem key={product.id} product={product} /> 
  ));
}
```

This is the JSON format of the strapi return:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "attributes": {
                "name": "The Contemplation of Union",
                "description_long": "The graphite pencil work that started it all.  Captured second place at the prestigious Brownlee O. Curry Art Competition.",
                "price": 399,
                "createdAt": "2022-05-01T02:07:51.795Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-05-01T02:07:54.191Z",
                "publishedAt": "2022-05-01T02:07:54.189Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Homage to Dali",
                "description_long": "The seminal dedication and homage to the great Salvador Dali. Here is the Soft Construction with Boiled Beans (Premonition of Spanish Civil War)",
                "price": 599,
                "createdAt": "2022-05-01T02:08:52.013Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-05-01T02:08:53.458Z",
                "publishedAt": "2022-05-01T02:08:53.456Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Still Life with Melon",
                "description_long": "Still life painted alla prima with juicy Melon and found objects",
                "price": 399,
                "createdAt": "2022-05-01T02:09:49.536Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-05-01T02:09:50.840Z",
                "publishedAt": "2022-05-01T02:09:50.839Z"
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "page": 1,
            "pageSize": 25,
            "pageCount": 1,
            "total": 3
        }
    }
}
```

When running this I get back the request as a 200, so the data and the fetch happens. I don't think I am referring to the data the appropriate way.

Comment: I posted an answer. Can you check? But on your own you can try to debug this, just render a dummy button and click it to console log the "products" data that you are trying to use. Make sure it is in the correct format before doing any kinda mapping in JSX. Check my answer for a quick reference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you render a dummy button like that, just click to console log the "products" to make sure they are in the format that you want.

```js
export default function ProductList() {
  const { data: products, isLoading } = useQuery('Products', () => 
    axios('/api/products').then((res) => res.data)
  );

  if (isLoading) return <LoadingSpinner />

  return 
    <div>
    <button onClick={() => console.log("products", products)}>Click to see products</button>
    {products.data.map((product) => (
      <ProductItem key={product.id} product={product} /> 
    ))}
  </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with React-Query, but what i noticed is that the JSON response doesn't have a property products, only data.

So the react code would need to look like this:

```
export default function ProductList() {
  const { data: products, isLoading } = useQuery('Products', () => 
    axios('/api/products').then((res) => res.data)
  );

  if (isLoading) return <LoadingSpinner />

  return products.map((product) => (
    <ProductItem key={product.id} product={product} /> 
  ));
}
```

Hope this helps.